# Does a websocket connection to an external server go through website or direct?

Tags: websocket

So lets say I have a game

[Browser] --------- [Web server]

the browser connects to a website and gets the game client displayed in an html page. Lets say the server for the game i want to connect to is 1.2.3.4 . Does my websocket connection to 1.2.3.4 go direct from me to this ip or does it go from me, through the web server and then to the websocket server.

I searched all over and couldn't find an answer.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it is the game client itself opening a websocket, then it will go directly from the client to the specified IP (1.2.3.4).